# How to call more than one web service in Arduino/Galileo Gen 2

Tags: arduino

I'm working on Galileo gen 2;
And I'm trying to use the following two web services:

1. `POST /dashboard/read_write_ard.php?temp="+tempValue`
2. `POST /dashboard/appinsert.php?valeur="+tempValue`

The first one inserts into table one...
and the second one will be used only if (`tempValue < 24`).

This is my code so far:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "rgb_lcd.h"

rgb_lcd lcd;      
const int pinLight = A1;
const int pinLed   = 13; 
const int thresholdvalue = 400; 
const int  idealLightValue = 400 ;  

const int pinTemp = A0;
const int B = 3975;
int etat=0;

const int pinSound = A2;
byte mac[] = {
      0x98, 0x4F, 0xEE, 0x05, 0x37, 0x33
};//adress mac du carte 

EthernetClient client;
IPAddress server(192,168, 1,7); 
void setup() {

     Serial.begin(9600);  
        pinMode(pinLed, OUTPUT);  
      lcd.begin(16, 2);
      delay(1000);

      system("ifup eth0");

   if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {

     Serial.println("\nFailed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");    
     delay(500);
  }

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }

  void loop() {
     system("ifup eth0");
    digitalWrite(pinLed, HIGH);    

    lcd.print("Starting to loop ");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();

    int TempSensorValue = analogRead(pinTemp);
    int LightSensorValue = analogRead(pinLight);
    int SoundSensorValue = analogRead(pinSound);
    float resistance = (float)(1023-TempSensorValue)*10000/TempSensorValue;
    int temperature = 1/(log(resistance/10000)/B+1/298.15)-273.15;
    Serial.println( temperature);
    Serial.println(SoundSensorValue);
    Serial.println( LightSensorValue);


     delay(1000); 

   String chEtat = "POST /dashboard/read_write_ard.php?temp=";
          chEtat += temperature ;
          chEtat += "&light=";
          chEtat += LightSensorValue;
          chEtat +="&sound=";
          chEtat +=SoundSensorValue;



 if (client.connect(server, 80)  ) {
     Serial.println("connected");

    lcd.print("Connected ");
     delay(500);
     lcd.clear();

      if (temperature <= 40 ){
    String chEtat2 = "POST /dashboard/appinsert.php?valeur=";
     chEtat2 += temperature ;
      chEtat2 += "&type=temperature" ;
    client.println(chEtat2);
    client.println(chEtat);

    }else{

      client.println(chEtat);
      client.println();

      }

  }


  while (client.available()) {
char c = client.read();
   Serial.print(c);

  } 
 if(client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
           lcd.print("Dissconnecting");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    client.stop();
    for (;;);
  }
}
```

I have a database containing 2 tables - one for alert values like temperature and the other for normal cases - so I want to put a code when my cart Galileo can add in table 1 : the normal one.

And in case of temperature, let's say more than 24, the value of that temperature will be added to the second table using the web service created for that.

I'd like to know how to get these data soon.